# How can I achieve multiple inheritance with fabricJS objects?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, fabricjs, multiple-inheritance

I want to create a new `fabric.MyObject` that simply is a `fabric.Object` but with some special props and methods. So I'm creating a `fabric.MyObject` that just calls `initialize` on `fabric.Object` and everything is fine.

Now I want to have special shapes like `MyRect`, `MyCircle` and so on that should inherit from `MyObject` as they should share the specials served by it.

I'm struggeling on how to make for example `MyRect` that inherits from `fabric.Rect` and also uses the props of `MyObject` as `fabric.Rect` just inherits from `fabric.Object` (and I don't want to change that as I may need "normal" rects as well).

Some hints would be appreciated :)

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");

//create new object that has some defaults changed
fabric.MyObject = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Object, {
    type: "myObject",
    
    initialize: function (options) {
   this.callSuper("initialize", fabric.util.object.extend({
         hasControls: true,
            cornerColor: "black",
            transparentCorners: false,
            hasBorders: false,
            fill: "rgba(255,0,0,.5)",
            stroke: "black",
            perPixelTargetFind: true
        }, options));
  }
});

//create new rect that builds up on the custom MyObject
fabric.MyRect = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {
    type: "myRect",
 
    initialize: function (options) {
   //how can I make it work that fabric.Rect is not using fabric.Object but fabric.MyObject instead?
        this.callSuper("initialize", options);
    }
});

//creates just a "normal" rect
canvas.add(new fabric.MyRect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  width: 100,
  height: 100
}));
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a straightforward way to do this. Rect calls `fabric.util.createClass` with `fabric.Object`.

Either you could just overwrite values in `fabric.Object` or you create an object with a bunch of defaults and pass that into all your `fabric.MyRect` and `fabric.MyCircle` classes.

It would be interesting if you could do what you were proposing and perhaps it's a [feature you could propose to fabricjs directly](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues).

Comment: I will ask on github for it for sure if there's really no way to actually do this.

Comment: you could also just copy the class creation file from the repo for Rect and pass in your own object class instead. We've done some stuff like that in our own project.